# How to write a text file based guest book with an "Admin area"?

Tags: php

I have to code a guest book where you can post new entries (with a check if name, email, title and content is filled in), see all entries (latest one on the very top) and, the hardest part, an admin area in which an admin (accessible with an admin username and a admin password) can delete and edit posts.

We are not allowed to use JavaScript or any databases like MySQL. I have to manage all this with only a few .php files and a max number of 2 .txt files.

The first half of this project is already finished. I can see my posts and I can write new ones. But the Admin Area is proving very difficult to implement. My question now is, how should I manage the writing to my "posts.txt" file if i want to be able to delete certain posts or even edit posts later on?

Here is the code that I've already got:

**My index page (which shows all the entries):**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="guestBook">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>Müller's farm | Home</title>
  </head>
<body>


<a href="start.php">Home</a>
<a href="newEntry.php">post a new comment</a>
<a href="administration.php">Administration</a>



<h2> All Entrys:</h2>
<?php

////output
 if (is_file("eintraege.txt")) {
    $handle = fopen("eintraege.txt", "r");
 
        if ($handle != FALSE) {
        
            while (!feof($handle)) { // Schleife bis zum Dateiende
            $zeile = fgets($handle); // liest aktuelle Zeile
            echo $zeile . "<br>";
            }
        
        fclose($handle);
        } else {
    echo "<p>error</p>";
        }
} else {
    echo "<p>name is not a name</p>";
    }




?>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**My "new entry" page (where you have to fill in all the conditions):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Berechnung dual">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Müller's Farm | Eintrag</title>
  </head>
<body>

<h2>Es freut uns das sie sich Zeit nehmen einen Eintrag in unserem Gästebuch zu hinterlassen.</h2>

<a href="start.php">Home</a>
<br>


<p> Bitte füllen sie diese Felder aus: </p>
<form action="newEntry.php" method="post">
 
<p>Autor:
<input type="text" name="autor">
</p>

<p>Titel:
<input type="text" name="titel">
</p>

<p>E-Mail:
<input type="email" name="mail">
</p>

<p>Text:
<textarea  name= "text" rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Hier ihren Gästebucheintrag schreiben"></textarea>
</p>
 
 <p>
<input type="submit" value="absenden">
</p>

</form>

<?php
    
//check ob alle felder befüllt sind 
if ( !isset ($_POST['autor']) ||
    trim($_POST['autor']) == '' ||
    !isset ($_POST['titel']) ||
    trim($_POST['titel']) == '' ||
    !isset ($_POST['mail']) ||
    trim($_POST['mail']) == '' ||
    !isset ($_POST['text']) ||
    trim($_POST['text']) == '' ) 
    {
    
        echo "Bitte füllen sie alle Felder aus!";
    //prüft mit der function "strpos" an welcher stelle '@' ist, wenn es nicht vorkommt gibt es false => ungültig
    }elseif(strpos($_POST['mail'],'@') == false){
        
        echo "Bitte achten sie darauf das sie eine gültige E-mail Adresse angeben!";
        
    //sind alle anforderungen erfüllt (alle felder befüllt und ein @ vorhanden) werden daten in variablen gespeichert
    } else{  
    //daten werden aus dem formular geholt
    $autor = htmlspecialchars($_POST['autor']);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['titel']);
    $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
    $content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);

    //funktion "nl2br" übernimmt auch vom benutzer eingegebene zeilen umbrüche in $content
    $content = nl2br($content);
 
    //öffnet die .txt file , schreibt an ende (a)
    $handle = fopen("eintraege.txt", "c");
    if ($handle == FALSE) {
        echo "<p>Datei konnte nicht zum Schreiben geöffnet werden</p>";
        die("<p>Das Programm wird beendet.</p>");
    }


    //schreiben der neuen informationen in jeweils neue zeilen
     if (fwrite($handle,utf8_decode("\n $autor \n $title \n $mail \n $content \n"))) {
         echo"Ihr Eintrag wurde in das Gästebuch aufgenommen.";
         
    } else {
    echo "<p>Das Schreiben der Daten ist fehlgeschlagen.</p>";
    }
    //schließen des dokuments
    fclose($handle);

    }   


 ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your admin area, make a php page that reads all of the entries from your text file into an array - they will then have a numeric index, print each out along with say a checkbox - you can use the uniq index to identify which post should be deleted - remove it from the array (by its index) and write the remaining array back to the file.

Comment: In order that readers do not unnecessarily duplicate effort, let's [declare the cross-posting to Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/g2yntc/guest_book_with_admin_area_help/).

Comment: It looks like you are writing a single guest book record to `eintraege.txt` in this code. However I assume that one entry will overwrite the other? If so, the advice on your Reddit post was quite good - use a file per entry, so you can write them independently without worrying about overwrites. You could put multiple guest book entries in a single file, but that is harder to do correctly.